# How to add a zoom in on touch for image view in android flip animator

Tags: android, animation, zooming, ontouch

```
public class FlipViewFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "FlipViewFragment";

    public static Boolean autoplay = false;
    FlipViewController flipView = null;

    Context mContext;

    public Boolean autoplaycompleted = false;

    ImageView imageDetail;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    float scale = 1f;

    ScaleGestureDetector SGD;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_flipview,
                container, false);

        imageDetail = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageDetail.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                SGD.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return ViewFlipViewLayout();
        // return rootView;
    }

    public View ViewFlipViewLayout() {
        ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        images.add(R.drawable.image1);
        images.add(R.drawable.image2);
        images.add(R.drawable.image3);


        // You can also use FlipViewController.VERTICAL
        flipView = new FlipViewController(getActivity(),
                FlipViewController.HORIZONTAL);

        // We're creating a NoteViewAdapter instance, by passing in the current
        // context and the
        // values to display after each flip
        flipView.setAdapter(new ImageViewAdapter(getActivity(), images));
        // flipView.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);
        // setContentView(flipView);

        return flipView;
    }

    public void AutoPlayAlbum() {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Running",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (autoplay) {
                    if (flipView.autoFlip()) {
                        AutoPlayAlbum();
                    } else {
                        Context mContext = MainActivity.mContext;
                        ((MainActivity) mContext).btnAutoPlay
                                .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                        autoplay = false;

                        ((MainActivity) mContext).mPlayer.pause();
                        ((MainActivity) mContext).length = ((MainActivity) mContext).mPlayer
                                .getCurrentPosition();
                        ((MainActivity) mContext).btnSound
                                .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_silent_mode);
                        autoplaycompleted = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 6000);

    }

    public void restartAutoPlay() {
        Log.e("Restart", "true");
        // flipView.restartFlip(getActivity(), FlipViewController.HORIZONTAL);
        // Reload current fragment
        Fragment frg = null;
        frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ARG_ITEM_ID);
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(frg);
        ft.attach(frg);
        ft.commit();
    }

    private void GarbageCollector() {
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }

    public class ImageViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



        ImageView imgView;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        int bmpWidth, bmpHeight;

        // Touch event related variables
        int touchState;
        final int IDLE = 0;
        final int TOUCH = 1;
        final int PINCH = 2;
        float dist0, distCurrent;

        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<Integer> images;

        public ImageViewAdapter(Context currentContext,
                ArrayList<Integer> allImages) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(currentContext);
            images = allImages;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View layout = convertView;

            GarbageCollector();

            if (convertView == null) {
                layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_flipview, null);
            }

            // Get's value from our ArrayList by the position
            Integer image = images.get(position);

            imgView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            // imgView.setText(note);
            // imgView.setImageResource(image);

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image);
            bmpWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
            bmpHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

            distCurrent = 1; // Dummy default distance
            dist0 = 1; // Dummy default distance
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imgView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                    return false;
                }
            });
            // imgView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            //
            // @Override
            // public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            // SGD.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            // return true;
            // }
            // });

            /*
             * Context mContext = MainActivity.mContext; RelativeLayout
             * container = (RelativeLayout) ((MainActivity) mContext)
             * .findViewById(R.id.content_container); container.bringToFront();
             */

            return layout;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to add a zoom in and zoom out for the image view on the touch of the image.The image should go to its default size after flipping.After flipping from one image to another it have to go to its original size

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ZoomableImageView extends ImageView
{
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
static final int CLICK = 3;
int mode = NONE;

PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 4f;
float[] m;

float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;
float width, height;
float saveScale = 1f;
float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
Context context;

public ZoomableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
{
    super(context, attr);
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                //when one finger is touching
                //set the mode to DRAG
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                //when two fingers are touching
                //set the mode to ZOOM
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    break;
                //when a finger moves
                //If mode is applicable move image
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //if the mode is ZOOM or
                    //if the mode is DRAG and already zoomed
                    if (mode == ZOOM || (mode == DRAG && saveScale > minScale))
                    {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;// x difference
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;// y difference
                        float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);// width after applying current scale
                        float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);// height after applying current scale
                        //if scaleWidth is smaller than the views width
                        //in other words if the image width fits in the view
                        //limit left and right movement
                        if (scaleWidth < width)
                        {
                            deltaX = 0;
                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }
                        //if scaleHeight is smaller than the views height
                        //in other words if the image height fits in the view
                        //limit up and down movement
                        else if (scaleHeight < height)
                        {
                            deltaY = 0;
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);
                        }
                        //if the image doesnt fit in the width or height
                        //limit both up and down and left and right
                        else
                        {
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);

                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }
                        //move the image with the matrix
                        matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                        //set the last touch location to the current
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;
                //first finger is lifted
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;
                // second finger is lifted
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
            }
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
{
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
    bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x)
{
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale)
        {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        }
        else if (saveScale < minScale)
        {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height)
        {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
            if (mScaleFactor < 1)
            {
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                {
                    if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width)
                    {
                        if (y < -bottom)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                        else if (y > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (x < -right)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                        else if (x > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (x < -right)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                else if (x > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                if (y < -bottom)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                else if (y > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    //Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    float scaleX =  width / bmWidth;
    float scaleY = height / bmHeight;
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    saveScale = 1f;

    // Center the image
    redundantYSpace = height - (scale * bmHeight) ;
    redundantXSpace = width - (scale * bmWidth);
    redundantYSpace /= 2;
    redundantXSpace /= 2;

    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

    origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
    origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

}

Comment: how to implement this class

Comment: create a class "ZoomableImageView" in your project . then in your xml file(layout) use this class instead of Imageview .